# Linux Mint LAN Connecting But Not Working

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint, lan

I am new to Linux and working on Linux Mint 17.2 on my laptop.

I am able to connect using LAN wire (i.e. on the right bottom it shows connected) but not able to access the internet. It works great on Wifi, but not working at all on LAN connection. I tried with the same LAN wire and same IP address on my friend's laptop (Windows), and it is working.

I have tried many things from [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet#TOC-No-wireless-connection-at-all), like installing a firmware package and driver, but no success. I also can't find any question on any forum where it shows that **LAN is connected and then it isn't working**. Please help me. I am new to this so I might be making some obvious mistake.

Comment: Can you ping your router's IP? Does `ping 8.8.8.8` work?

Comment: @ecube Yes, doing that (using Wifi) gives response like: "64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=25.8 ms" in multiple lines. So I guess that's considered to be working?

Comment: In that case, this might be a DNS problem. Try setting the DNS servers in your network config to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and see if that solves the issue (https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)